# Can a multiclass Eldritch Knight/Mage of Lorehold Wizard benefit from War Magic and Lessons of the past at the same time?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, multiattack

I was considering a multiclass Eldritch Knight/Mage of Lorehold Wizard.

The Eldritch Knight feature *War Magic* states

> when you use your action to cast a cantrip, you can make one weapon attack as a bonus action.

And Mage of Lorehold Wizard's *Lesson of the past-Warrior* says

> If you use your action to cast a cantrip, you can make one weapon attack as part of that action.

My question is, as both classes use the Wizard spell list, and both classes can cast the same cantrip, **can I benefit from both at once?** As one is a part of that action and the other is a bonus action? So cast a cantrip, melee attack as part of that action, then melee again as a bonus action. Or is it one or the other?

Comment: Rather weird how the designers created these two class features which are supposed to do the same thing (you get to make a weapon attack when you cast a cantrip) but use slightly different mechanics to achieve that. I wonder if there was any intention behind that or if it was simply an oversight.

Comment: @Philipp given how the second one doesn't use any case of resource and is newer it would probably be case so called "power creep"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You can make two attacks

The two abilities aren't at odds because only one uses a limited resource (a bonus action which you have only one per turn). Even if you made a weapon attack *as part of the Action" you used your action to cast the cantrip and so can use your bonus action for another attack.

The spell list or the specific cantrip cast are unimportant so long as an Action is used since both features simply require a cantrip be cast as Action.

Of course these two attacks are in addition to any attacks the cantrip lets you make. Those can even be a weapon attack as well in case of *Booming Blade* or *Green Flame Blade*.

Comment: What if that cantrip is Booming Blade or GFB?

Comment: @nonymous I don't think this changes anything. While this adds another attack, an Action is still used to cast a cantrip.